# Do something if first line of infile != something, if it is; continue

Tags: python, io

I am reading a bunch of files, I want the program to check if the first line in the file is equal to something spesific, if it is, I want to continue loading the rest of the lines, if not, append some standard string to signal that I have no data.

```
inputlines = []
try:
    #This is just to check if the file exists
    infile = open('snip...', 'r')
except IOError:
    print "NODATA"
    return 0

for line in infile:
    if not(<first line in the file> == <something>):
        inputlines.append("NODATA")
        return 0
    inputlines.append(line)
```

Is this doable in some smart built in way in python, or do I need to drop every line into inputlines, and then search inputlines to see if the first element is what I want it to be? Because that seems like a lot of extra work if I had say 10 000 files.

I guess the TL;DR question is; Is there some way to identify the first line in an infile?

Comment: You could get the line numbers with e.g. `for index, line in enumerate(infile):`, then test the index accordingly. Or just grab the first line with `first_line = next(infile)` before entering the loop.

Comment: `first_line = next(infile)` worked perfectly, thank you! And I think I might need to use enumerate in a different part of the program. Cheers